# Getting conditionNotMet error on migration of emails > 32kb in size

Tags: gmail, google-apps, google-admin-sdk, google-email-migration

I've had success migrating small test messages with the [Google Email Migration API v2](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-migration). However, when migrating larger messages, I get an error like:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "conditionNotMet",
    "message": "Limit reached.",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "If-Match"
   }
  ],
  "code": 412,
  "message": "Limit reached."
 }
}
```

I start noticing the error sporadically with messages at 32kb size. At about 40kb in size, the error becomes consistent (no messages succeed). I've confirmed the error occurs whether I'm using [google-api-python-client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/) with [my non-standard discovery document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17689182/discovery-document-for-google-email-migration-api-v2/17704873#17704873) or the [OAuth 2.0 playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground). Here's what a successful call and response for a message < 32kb looks like:

```
POST /upload/email/v2/users/jay@ditoweb.com/mail?uploadType=multipart HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-length: 6114
Content-type: multipart/related; boundary="part_boundary"
Authorization: Bearer <removed>
--part_boundary
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{
 'isInbox': 'true',
 'isUnread': 'true'
}

--part_boundary
Content-Type: message/rfc822

From: <admin@jay.powerposters.org>
To: <admin@jay.powerposters.org>
Subject: test growing message sizes
Date: Wed, 17 Jul 2013 10:40:48 -0400

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
<last line repeated ~50 times>
--part_boundary--


HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Content-length: 0
Via: HTTP/1.1 GWA
X-google-cache-control: remote-fetch
Server: HTTP Upload Server Built on Jul 8 2013 15:32:26 (1373322746)
Etag: "S82oyh6kQMvIt9YE14Ogc8RmmsQ/vyGp6PvFo4RvsFtPoIWeCReyIC8"
Date: Wed, 17 Jul 2013 17:35:13 GMT
```

and here's what a failed message of ~150kb looks like:

```
POST /upload/email/v2/users/admin@jay.powerposters.org/mail?uploadType=multipart HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-length: 189946
Content-type: multipart/related; boundary="part_boundary"
Authorization: Bearer <removed>
--part_boundary
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{
 'isInbox': 'true',
 'isUnread': 'true'
}

--part_boundary
Content-Type: message/rfc822

From: <admin@jay.powerposters.org>
To: <admin@jay.powerposters.org>
Subject: test growing message sizes
Date: Wed, 17 Jul 2013 10:40:48 -0400

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
<last line repeated ~1500 times>

--part_boundary--


HTTP/1.1 412 Precondition Failed
Content-length: 240
Via: HTTP/1.1 GWA
X-google-cache-control: remote-fetch
Server: HTTP Upload Server Built on Jul 8 2013 15:32:26 (1373322746)
Date: Wed, 17 Jul 2013 16:57:23 GMT
Content-type: application/json
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "conditionNotMet",
    "message": "Limit reached.",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "If-Match"
   }
  ],
  "code": 412,
  "message": "Limit reached."
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has fixed the issue on their end. I can now migrate messages of all sizes.